# Mixed Content error due to doubleclick ad dot.gif

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, mixed

Im getting a mixed content error on my website, when I locate it trough Chrome's tools, I see it's because a 1x1 image called dot.gif is loaded over http

You can see it on the image I included:[image: dot.gif mixed content]

I searched my database and all my files but I can't find it anywhere.

Anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a tracking pixel. Probably from an ad server or a plugin you're using.

Check the source code for any plugins you're using. If you don't find it, it's probably being added by a 3rd party script from an ad network.

Comment: I did check the source code and the database, I couldn't find anything. Bit weird that I can't control that tracking code pixel and that I can't help it that it renders my site to have mixed content.